# Why does java.util.Calendar return minimal WEEK_OF_MONTH value as zero?

Tags: java, calendar, week-number

I'm trying to set minimal value of WEEK_OF_MONTH field as follows:

```
calendar.set(WEEK_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMinimum(WEEK_OF_MONTH));
```

The call to

```
calendar.getActualMinimum(WEEK_OF_MONTH)
```

returns 0

But at calculation during get* operations this field becomes 5.
Moreover, without leniency mode, I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WEEK_OF_MONTH: 0 -> 5 // or MONTH: 9 -> 8
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
    at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:2265)
    at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:1826)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

If I set WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1, then I get it correctly as 1.

Check out an [example](https://repl.it/repls/BigWeepyUsers)

Can anyone clarify such a behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The calendar week starts at 0.

Comment: Probably using the `GrgorianCalendar` which [states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) "Week 1 of a month (the days with WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1) is the earliest set of at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() contiguous days in that month...  Days of a month before week 1 have a WEEK_OF_MONTH of 0.", but not sure what the question is meant to be....

Comment: You shouldn’t need to worry. The `Calendar` class is long outdated and has a range of design problems with it, so I recommend you don’t use it. Instead use an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `ZonedDateTime` is the most natural replacement, but if you are only interested in dates (not times), `LocalDate` is better.

Comment: Some quick tests on my Java 11 seem to indicate that `Calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` returns 0 always, even in `US` locale where the first day of the month is always in week 1 of the month. A quick search for a description of a bug that might cause this didn’t seem to turn up anything.

Comment: @achAmháin ok, done it already

Comment: @CyanCoding yes it is. java.util.GregorianCalendar#MIN_VALUES[WEEK_OF_MONTH] = 0, but why do I get week #5 or month #8 (+1 = September)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

```
    Locale russia = Locale.forLanguageTag("ru-RU");
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(russia);

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));
    int minimumWeekOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).get(wf.weekOfMonth());
    System.out.println("Minimum week of month: " + minimumWeekOfMonth);
    LocalDate dateInFirstWeekOfMonth = date.with(wf.weekOfMonth(), minimumWeekOfMonth);
    System.out.println("Date in first week of month: " + dateInFirstWeekOfMonth);
```

When running this snippet just now I got the following output:

```
Minimum week of month: 1
Date in first week of month: 2018-10-05
```

I have assumed that you are in Russian locale. Russia uses the international week numbering where Monday is the first day of the week and week one of a year or month is the first week that contains at least 4 days of the year or month. So week 1 of October 2018 was from Monday October 1 through Sunday October 7. This in turn means that the minumum week in this month is 1. Starting out from today (a Friday) and setting the week of month to 1 gives Friday in week 1, that is, Friday October 5.

If I start out from Wednesday September 12 instead I get:

```
Minimum week of month: 0
Date in first week of month: 2018-08-29
```

Week 1 of September was from Monday September 3 through September 9. This means that September 1 and 2 were in week 0, so 0 is the minimum week of month for September. And when starting from a Wednesday I set week number to 0, I get the Wednesday of that week, which happens to lie in August: August 29. If we ask for the week of month of that date, do we get 0?

```
    System.out.println("Week of month: " + dateInFirstWeekOfMonth.get(wf.weekOfMonth()));
```

Output:

```
Week of month: 5
```

Since the date is in August, we now get which week of August the date is in, which happens to be week 5.

### What happened in your code?

It seems to me that `GregorianCalendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` always returns 0. I cannot make sense of this observation. Since Russia uses the Gregorian calendar, an instance of `GregorianCalendar` is what you really get from `Calendar.getInstance`.

I wouldn’t want to bother. As I said in a comment already, the Calendar class is long outdated and has a range of design problems with it, so I recommend you don’t use it. I’d certainly prefer java.time, the modern Java date and time API, any time.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: "international week numbering" is not quite the right phrasing. Russia has its own cultural norms. In this case, first day of the week, that norm happens to be the same as has been adopted by many other countries and by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard.